# How to mark file as source in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I notice that any class not found in eclipse after **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>** push.

I notice that I cannot see files, that expose so:

[image]

And following classes find good:

[image]

How to mark file as source code file in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the directory as `Source Folder` in order to make Eclipse treat files as source

You can find the setting in project properties.

Comment: what setting should I find?

Comment: I don't have Eclipse right now, but I think it is under the `build path`

Answer (score 1):

Create `Source Folder` in your Project and copy your source code in there. Follow following steps:

1. Right click on your project.
2. select `New`
3. create source folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or could it be, that you need to tick the Label Decorations in Preferences->Appearance->Label Decorations "Java Type Indicator"?